# How to set a breakpoint in HTML-code with Google Chrome Developer Tool in the context of AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following line of HTML-code i.e.:

```
<button ng-click="round.won=true" ng-class="{'active':round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Gewonnen</button>
```

It is not clear to me, which function has been called in which file when having clicked a button and fired the ng-click-event.

So I wonder how to set a breakpoint in Google Chrome Developer Tool next to `ng-click="round.won=true"` in order to jump into the related Javascript-function/file?

Comment: Not possible. I suggest searching your entire project directory for something like `$scope.adjustedYesNo` since these properties *must* live on `$scope` somewhere. Once you track down the JS, just debug that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set breakpoints on HTML code. However if your code was something like below:

**HTML**

```html
<button ng-click="winRound()" ng-class="{'active':round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Gewonnen</button>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller(function($scope) {
  $scope.winRound = function() {
     $scope.round.win = true;
  }
});
```

Then you could have set a breakpoint inside the winRound function in the JS file. But make sure that your JS code (controller) is places in a separate JS file and not inside the script tag in HTML.